# Convert audio into raw PCM data of type [Double]

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, avaudiofile

I'm trying to convert a recorded audio file into raw PCM data of type [Double]. I found a way to load and convert audio to PCM data of the type [Float32] like this:

```
    // load audio from path
    let file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: self.soundFileURL)
    // declare format
    let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .PCMFormatFloat32, sampleRate: file.fileFormat.sampleRate, channels: 1, interleaved: false)
    // initialize audiobuffer with the length of the audio file
    let buf = AVAudioPCMBuffer(PCMFormat: format, frameCapacity: UInt32(file.length))
    // write to file
    try! file.readIntoBuffer(buf)
    // copy to array
    let floatArray = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buf.floatChannelData[0], count:Int(buf.frameLength)))
```

The problem is, I need the data as [Double] and AVAudioPCMBuffer() only knows the `.PCMFormatFloat32`. Does anybody know a workaround?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But `AVAudioFormat` *does* know `.PCMFormatFloat64`:

```
let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .PCMFormatFloat64, sampleRate: file.fileFormat.sampleRate, channels: 1, interleaved: false)
```

Maybe you mean `AVAudioPCMBuffer` doesn't have a `float64ChannelData` convenience property?

That's fine, you can use `AVAudioPCMBuffer`'s superclass, `AVAudioBuffer`  has everying you need to be able to get at the raw `Double`/`Float64` samples:

```
let abl = buf.audioBufferList.memory
let doubles = UnsafePointer<Double>(abl.mBuffers.mData)
doubles[0] // etc...
```

In full:

```
let file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: self.soundFileURL)
let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .PCMFormatFloat64, sampleRate: file.fileFormat.sampleRate, channels: 1, interleaved: false)

let buf = AVAudioPCMBuffer(PCMFormat: format, frameCapacity: UInt32(file.length))
try! file.readIntoBuffer(buf)
let abl = buf.audioBufferList.memory
let doubles = UnsafePointer<Float64>(abl.mBuffers.mData)
```

Comment: What happens when you `readIntoBuffer()`? It works for me. I updated the question to show the entire code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, solved my problem! I didn't get that I still had use the AVAudioPCMBuffer.

Answer (score 4):

updated to ***Swift 5***

```
        do {
            let file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: soundFileURL)
            if let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat64, sampleRate: file.fileFormat.sampleRate, channels: file.fileFormat.channelCount, interleaved: false), let buf = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(file.length)){
                try file.read(into: buf)
                let abl = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buf.audioBufferList, count: Int(buf.audioBufferList.pointee.mNumberBuffers)))

                let buffer = buf.audioBufferList[0].mBuffers
                let mDataList = Array(UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer(start: buffer.mData, count: Int(buffer.mDataByteSize)))
            }
        } catch{
            print("Audio Error: \(error)")
        }
```

Comment: mDataList isn't of type [Double]

Answer (score 1):

that code doesn't work anymore maybe.
here is new working code.

**Swift 3.2**

```
let file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: soundFileURL)
let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .PCMFormatFloat64, sampleRate: file.fileFormat.sampleRate, channels: file.fileFormat.channelCount, interleaved: false)
let buf = AVAudioPCMBuffer(PCMFormat: format, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(file.length))
try! file.readIntoBuffer(buf)
let abl = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buf.audioBufferList, count: Int(buf.audioBufferList.pointee.mNumberBuffers)))
let buffer = audioBufferList[0].mBuffers
let mDataList = Array(UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer(start: buffer.mData, count: Int(buffer.mDataByteSize)))
```